# Selection in the Dashboard to reflect in the drop-down in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: data-science, tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have created the dashboard as the cascading filter(1 filter when selected affects the choice of other filters) which is working fine in attached Sample. 
 But I want that --> when I click on the house h2 within the sheet , that should get reflected in the drop down value .

eg: In the image below when I click on the h2 since the h2 has changed the value of other sheets as well --> I want the drop-down of filter to reflect "h2" as well instead of "All"

[image]

Comment: Action filter DO NOT influence drop-down filters

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality using a parameter and a calculated field.

1. Create a parameter "Selected house color" with data type "String". In the "Values" section enter all house color (h1, h2, h3, ....).
2. Create a calculated field as "Selected house color filter", in the formula section, enter the following formula:

   IF [House color] = [Selected house color] THEN [House color] END
3. Add filter "Selected house color filter"
4. Add an action to update the parameter. In add action choose "Change Parameter." Name the action (e.g., "Select House Color").Select the bar chart as the source sheet.
   Choose "Select" as the action type.
   In the "Target" section, select the parameter you created earlier ("Selected house color").
   In the "Run action on" section, select "Select" under "Clearing the selection will" option.